# color org-agenda entries by level

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, faces, colors

My org agenda (I use it as a todo-list without dates with the `alltodo` type, generating a list of all todo entries for each file) has many entries with many subheadings (which can again have multiple subsubheadings). While indentation helps to some extent make it not like a big wall of text, I recently realized it would be nice to have coloring based on the level of the entry. Ideally I would like to apply the `org-level` faces, i.e. `org-level-1` to top-level entries, `org-level-2` to subheadings and so on. I searched a bit but couldn't find anything. Is this possible?